# In HTML5 : How to control the stretch of the bar? Is there any way to increase spaces in between the texts?

Tags: html, html-lists

**In HTML5** : How to control the stretch of the bar? Is there any way to increase spaces in between the texts?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMPL7UBRZEEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setiing width propery for **li** will do

```css
ul {padding: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width:150px;
}
ul { display: inline-block;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:right">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a margin to each link to create space between them.  Also if you wanted to stretch the nav you could set the width to 100%.

```
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 20px;
}

ul {
padding: 16px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333333;
width: 100%;
}
```